# Find E[X] and Var[X] of a particle moving along a graph

Tags: expected-value, variance

> A particle moves along the following graph
>
> 0 <---> 1 <---> 2
>
> If the particle is at 0, it will next move to 1. If the particle is at
> 1, it will next move to 0 with probability 0.99 and to 2 with
> probability 0.01. Starting at 0, let X denote the number of steps
> needed to reach 2.

I'm having trouble with this question. I tried to use X = X1 + X2 + X3 + ... , and i noticed that it can only reach 2 with even steps so I made a new variable Y = Y1 + Y2 + Y3 + ..., where Y represents the even round that it takes to reach and created a summation of $\sum_{i=1}^\infty 0.99^i(0.01)*2$ but I dont think its correct as it seems to tend to infinte

Comment: Is the 2 in your summation? There's no reason for it to be if there is.

Comment: _"I tried to use X = X1 + X2 + X3 + ... "_ What do you mean by $X_1$, $X_2$, ... here?

Comment: Hi, when i was doing the question, since X = num of steps needed to reach to 2, i was thinking of X = X1 + X2 + ... , where its a sum of random variables Xi, and i represents the number of steps to reach 2.

Comment: @Catt I don't quite get it. What exactly is the random variable $X_6$? Something about "6 steps to reach 2" but what kind of a random variable do you have for it?

Comment: I'm asking because to me it looks likely that your mistake is caused by not being clear (even to yourself) about what the symbols you use means and therefore computing the wrong thing.

Comment: Your $Y$ is a form of geometric random variable with a well known mean and variance, both finite.  $X=2Y$ so has twice the mean and four times the variance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The first thing to observe is that state $2$ can only be reached after an *even* number of steps, if starting at state $0$.  We can see this by coloring states $0$ and $2$ red, and coloring state $1$ blue.  Each transition from one state to another must change the color of the state we are in, either from red to blue, or from blue to red.  Since $0$ and $2$ share the same color, it is only possible to reach $2$ after an even number of color changes.

This also implies that if the number of steps is odd, then we are always at state $1$.

So suppose we have taken $2n-1$ steps for some positive integer $n$ but have not reached state $2$.  We are at state $1$, and the probability of being at state $2$ and stopping at the next step, is simply $0.01$.  In this case, we will have taken $X = 2n$ steps.  But with probability $0.99$, we will return to state $0$, after which we will again be at state $1$ after $2(n+1)-1 = 2n+1$ steps.  So the number $n$ represents the number of times we have entered state $1$.

To have reached state $1$ upon the $n^{\rm th}$ time without stopping at state $2$, we must have had consecutive $n-1$ failures to transition from state $1$ to state $2$.  So the probability of this event is simply $(0.99)^{n-1}$.  Then the probability of the next step ending at state $2$ is $(0.01)$ times this probability; hence
$$\Pr[X = 2n] = (0.01)(0.99)^{n-1}, \quad n \in \{1,2,\ldots\}.$$
consequently, $X/2$ is a geometric random variable with success parameter $p = 0.01$ and counts the number of times we have entered state $1$ before reaching state $2$, and $X$ is twice a geometric random variable that counts the number of steps to reach state $2$.

The mean and variance of $X$ are straightforward to calculate and are left as an exercise.

Comment: Thank you! I did not notice it was a geometric series and was trying to calculate using the formulas for discrete RVs

Comment: Hi, just to clarify Pr(X/2 = n) is the same as Pr(X = 2n) right?

Comment: @Catt That is correct.  $\Pr[X/2 = n] = \Pr[X = 2n]$.

Comment: Thank you very much! :)

Answer (score 1):

If we let $Y_i$ be the event that it reaches point 2 on the graph in $2i$ steps then the equation for the probability of $Y_i$ should be:

$P(Y_i) = (0.99)^{i-1}(.01)$ then the summation is equal to 1,

$\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}P(Y_i) = 1$